# C++ If/else prints out both outputs

Tags: c++

I am having problems with my if/then statement. It prints out both couts...

```
if (averageScore >= 60)
    {
        cout << "P\n";
    }
    else (averageScore <= 59);
    {
        cout << "F\n";
        cout << studentsName << " needs " << (60.0 - averageScore) << " additional points to pass the class.\n";
    }
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...
any advice?
thanks!

Comment: Look at the last character on your `else` line ...

Comment: You are missing an `if` after `else`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Note that `else (averageScore <= 59) ;` is parsed as `else { averageScore <= 50; }`

Comment: The `else` keyword in C++ doesn't take parameters. You either need to use `else if (averageScore <= 59)` with no `;` at the end of that line or you need to just use `else`. Also note that `if (averageScore >= 60)` did not pass, then it *must* implicitly be `<= 59` so your test is redundant. `if (averageScore >= 60) { cout << "P\n"; } else { cout << "F\n"; cout << etc ... << "\n"; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you code has typos

```
if (averageScore >= 60)
{
    cout << "P\n";
}
else if (averageScore <= 59) // this line
{
    cout << "F\n";
    cout << studentsName << " needs " << (60.0 - averageScore) << " additional points to pass the class.\n";
}
```

But since you are testing `averageScore` against `60`, you code could be simplified as (assumption, averageScore is an integer as suggested by @Amol)

```
if (averageScore >= 60)
{
    cout << "P\n";
}
else
{
    // if average score is an integer and it was not >= 60,
    // then it must implicitly be <= 59
    cout << "F\n";
    cout << studentsName << " needs " << (60.0 - averageScore) << " additional points to pass the class.\n";
}
```

If averageScore is not an integer, and you want to ignore cases where averageScore > 59 but < 60 (e.g. 59.5)

```
else if (averageScore <= 59)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: or like @Amol mentioned get rid of if (condition), just leave the else { ...

Comment: you are right. I will modify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`else (averageScore <= 59);` make `else` part without any code. Remove that `;` and you need to use only `else`. In code,  `else (averageScore <= 59)` is wrong. If you want to add condition for `else` then use `else if`

Comment: hint: else doesn't take parameters.

Comment: @kfsone : where it is mentioned that 'else' is taking parameters ?

Comment: In your answer, you say `else()`, which is wrong. `else` keyword must be followed by a statement, not parentheses. http://ideone.com/LpCAxy

Comment: @kfsone: I did not mean `else` with parameters, anyways edited my answer